# Background and transparent effect

Tags: html, css, background, cross-browser

http://codepen.io/alemarch/pen/yyeOwX

```
<div id="back">
  bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla 
</div>
<div id="front">g</div>
```

and css

```
 #back {
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: #000;
  color: 
}

#front {
  margin-top:-170px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;

  //position: relative;
}
```

This code work only with chrome.. I ask

1. How run in firefox? I must use svg?
2. In Chrome, how change only color of the bla bla bla (now if you use forecolor of bla bla different of background color the transparent effect is lost)?
3. Why, in chrome, if I change position (ex relative) transparent effect is lost too?

Thanks.

Comment: applying transparent color to the text makes no sense. it's like color to be none!

Comment: There is no `background-clip: text` in CSS specification nor in Firefox implementation. In fact `-webkit-background-clip: text;` is supported only in webkit-based web browsers.

Comment: You can achieve this with `svg` images used as a mask, if you _really_ wanted to.  You could even get super-fancy and do run-time replacement of text with those `svg` images using JavaScript.